# discord js v13 message reply don't work (prefix)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I was making discord bot that reply the user word with prefix.
example the user said `!Hello` the bot will reply with `Hello`

The error was
`(node:11208) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead (Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)`

So I changed the code message to messageCreate but the bot didn't reply either and have no error in the console log what should I change the code of my script?

this is the source code
`prefix is ! (It is in the config.json)`

> index.js
>
> ```js
> const {Client,Intents,Collection} = require("discord.js");
> const client = new Client ({intents:[Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS]})
> const fs = require("fs");
> const { token, prefix } = require("./config.json");
> client.commands = new Collection();
>
>
> const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands").filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js")); 
>
>  var data = []
> for(const file of commandFiles) {
>     const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);  
>     client.commands.set(command.name, command);
>      data.push({name:command.name,description:command.description,options:command.options});
>
> }
>
> client.once('ready', async () =>{ 
>     console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
>     // await client.guilds.cache.get('874178319434801192')?.commands.set(data)
>
>     setInterval(() => {
>         const statuses = [
>             'mimc!',
>             'wtf',
>             'prefix = !'
>         ]
>         const status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random()*statuses.length)] 
>         client.user.setActivity(status, {type: "PLAYING"})
>     }, 10000) 
>
> });
>
> client.on("messageCreate", (message) =>{ 
>     if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
>
>     const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/); 
>     const command = args.shift(); 
>
>     if(!client.commands.has(command)) return;
>
>     try{ 
>         client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
>     }
>     catch(error){
>         console.error(error);
>     }
>
> });
>
> client.login(token)
> ```

> Hello.js (in the folder of commands)
>
> ```js
> module.exports = {
> name: "Hello",
> description: "Say Hi",
> execute(message) {
>     return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, Hello.`)
> },
> };
> ```

Comment: Which version of Node.js is running on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

The code of index.js (or main file) goes by:

```js
  const {Client, Intents, MessageEmbed, Presence, Collection, Interaction}= require ('discord.js')
const client = new Client({intents:[Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]})
const TOKEN = ''// get your TOKEN!
const PREFIX = '!'
const fs = require('fs')

    client.commands = new Collection();
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
    
    client.on('ready', ()=> {
   console.log(' I am online!!')
   client.user.setActivity('A GAME ', {type: ('PLAYING')})
   client.user.setPresence({
       status: 'Online'
        })
      }) 

    client.on('message', message => {
        if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)|| message.author.bot) return 
        const arg = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(/ +/)
        const command= arg.shift().toLowerCase()
        if (command === 'ping'){
            client.commands.get('ping').execute(message,arg)

        }
       
   })
  
client.login(TOKEN)
```

After making a folder **commands**, add a new **.js** file, and name it as **ping.js**
The code for ping.js goes by -

```js
module.exports={
   name:'ping', 
   execute(message, arg){
       message.reply('hello!!')
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh It works thank u very very thank u I love u